# Upgrade Angular 13 to 14 and remaining package.json all package versions to latest

Tags: angular, npm, version-control, package.json, npm-package

I'm trying to migrate from Angular 13 to Angular 14 and I was able to do it by using the command ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14. I want to update the remaining packages here. version of the json file package that is compatible with Angular 14.

I was looking for information relating to upgrades when I discovered the following command: update all versions to the most recent versions.

1. ncu Checks for updates from the package.json file
2. ncu -u Update the package.json file
3. npm update --save Update your package-lock.json file from the package.json file

The aforementioned methods update Angular to version 15, which is the most recent version, but I do not want to upgrade Angular to version 15. Here, I want Angular 14, and the other package versions are the most recent with Angular 14-compatible versions. Is there a command to manage this kind of circumstance or do I need to manually review and update each package? Please assist me in getting clarification. I'm grateful.

Comment: You need to manually turn the angular packages back.